# What is the IP address of my iphone when my computer is connected to the internet using that iphone's personal hotspot?

Tags: iphone, tethering, network

I have this program on my mac that streams my gps location over the private network.

When on the road, my program needs an internet connection as well as the gps data, so I need to pair to my iphone to get internet. After doing this, however, my program can't determine my iphone's IP address so I can't get the location data.

Does my iphone have an IP address when it's the "router" effectively, via personal hotspot??

Comment: what program is it? and yes anything that connects to Internet will have a IP address.

Comment: the iOS app's name is gps2ip. Reading the data using qgis.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is `172.20.10.1`

Found this out by checking out the gps2ip settings and saw there were some provisions for using a personal hotspot and it told me there. You have to tell gps2ip to pipe over the hotspot from within the app to make it work regardless.

Comment: `172.20.10.1` is basically the ip address of your phone acting as a router. But it may not always be this number. It may be `172.20.10.2` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

It is the 'router' ipaddress see SystemPreferences–>Network (below), then click on Wi-Fi (should be green), then Advanced–>TCP/IP–>*Router=172.20.10.1* or *172.20.10.2* etc

[image]

[image]